# 3.5.1 Blender Grease Pencil Fill Tool not working

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I've drawn a character and I want to color his head, but the fill tool is not working.

I've redrawn the circle many times to ensure there are no gaps, and the fill tool is still not working. The material checks out, I'm on a different layer (but same grease pencil object), and I'm drawing with "automerge drawing" which supposedly helps with this issue.

I have a screen recording but I'm new here and I'm not sure how to upload that. My last resort would be to draw with both stroke and fill enabled, but then, I want to know how to fix this issue. I want to be able to just simply fill in my drawings.

Thanks, [image]